# Gcc is ignoring -Wno-unused-variable

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings

I'm using both `gcc version 4.8.3 20140624` and `gcc4.9.1` compiled from trunk. However, the flag doesn't seem to be ignored on [online compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1163d1d0c3718f14). Here is the test program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i;
}
```

And shell output:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-variable -I./ -c -o test.o test.cpp

test.cpp:6:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
     ^
test.cpp:6:5: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
```

Comment: And if you remove the optimization flag `-O2`?

Comment: unused-variable != unused-parameter...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg no difference

Comment: Oh, and the program you show doesn't match the compiler output. Please edit your question to show the correct program or the correct output.

Comment: Why do you include `<iostream>` when your code doesn't use any of its facilities?

Comment: On Mac OS X 10.9.4, G++ 4.9.1 generates a warning for `int main() { int i; }` with compiler options `g++ -O2 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -c test.cpp`, also with `-O3` instead, and `-Wextra` and `-Werror` (well, it generates an error then). I also get the warnings with GCC 4.8.2 (I don't have 4.8.3 compiled).  What platform are you on?  Where did you get your versions of GCC from?  (Mine are 'home-built'.)

Answer (score 1):

With the following program

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
}
```

with `g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-variable`
You don't have warning for unused-variable `i`.
if you don't want warning for parameter `argc`, `argv`,
add also the compiler flag `-Wno-unused-parameter`

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa56d71fc4cd9290)